# gdb doesn't hit break points for a simple ARM disassembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm, breakpoints

I'm studying ARM assembly at uni and I wrote a simple program to debug with `gdb` for fun. The problem is when I set a break point, it says the break point is set but does not actually stop at it.
The ARM source is here : http://pastebin.com/skwnniLy and it is supposed to sort the three values moved into r0 r1 and r2 at the beginning, from the lower the the greater.
I compiled it with `arm-none-eabi-as -gdwarf-2 -o sort.o sort.s`, so it does have debug options, and obj dump shows this:
*(TL;DR: everything is fine with the disassembly)*

```
qreon@Trillian:~$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -d sort.o
sort.o:     file format elf32-littlearm
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <init>:
   0:   e3a00491    mov r0, #-1862270976    ; 0x91000000
   4:   e3a0131a    mov r1, #1744830464     ; 0x68000000
   8:   e3a0232a    mov r2, #-1476395008    ; 0xa8000000

0000000c <compare>:
   c:   e1500001    cmp r0, r1
  10:   51a04000    movpl   r4, r0
  14:   51a03001    movpl   r3, r1
  18:   41a04001    movmi   r4, r1
  1c:   41a03000    movmi   r3, r0
  20:   e1520004    cmp r2, r4
  24:   51a07002    movpl   r7, r2
  28:   51a06004    movpl   r6, r4
  2c:   51a05003    movpl   r5, r3
  30:   5a000007    bpl 54 <end>
  34:   41530002    cmpmi   r3, r2
  38:   51a07004    movpl   r7, r4
  3c:   51a06003    movpl   r6, r3
  40:   51a05002    movpl   r5, r2
  44:   5a000002    bpl 54 <end>
  48:   41a07004    movmi   r7, r4
  4c:   41a06002    movmi   r6, r2
  50:   41a05003    movmi   r5, r3

00000054 <end>:
  54:   e1a00007    mov r0, r7
  58:   e1a01006    mov r1, r6
  5c:   e1a02005    mov r2, r5
  60:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  64:   e3a04000    mov r4, #0
  68:   e3a05000    mov r5, #0
  6c:   e3a06000    mov r6, #0
  70:   e3a07000    mov r7, #0
```

Then I launch `gdb`:

```
qreon@Trillian:~$ arm-none-eabi-gdb sort.o
GNU gdb (7.8-0ubuntu1+6) 7.8 [...]
Reading symbols from sort.o...done.
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0x74 vma 0x0
Start address 0x0
Transfer rate: 928 bits in <1 sec.
(gdb) b init
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4: file sort.s, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/qreon/sort.o 
[Inferior 1 (process 42000) exited normally]
```

What I notice is that the break point I set to label `init` is actually set to `line 4`, which is the second instruction below the `init` label in the source code. But even if it's not at the right place, I have a break point set on an instruction so the program should stop, and it doesn't. I thought it could be because of the two branches, but they are in the middle of the `compare` label, not in `init`...

Any ideas ? :(

Comment: Are you sure gdb is happy with an object file? I would definitely try to link it.

Comment: I did exactly this at uni ant it worked. :/ It was a different source though. How do you link an ARM object file ?

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-ld sort.o -o sort` for example.

Comment: are you cross-compiling to an embedded system?  If so, what mcu/programmer are you using?

Comment: Linking the object file fixed the problem with `gdb`. Thanks ! And I was compiling from a Debian machine.